# window.print() dialog not show graph in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have to print a report which has graph, when I use `window.print()` it shows graph in preview in all browser but not in chrome.

Following code i used:

```
function Print(strid)
{
    var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
    var WinPrint =window.open('','','letf=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.resizeTo(screen.width ,screen.height );
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
    prtContent.innerHTML=strOldOne;
}
```

Plz help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a timout before calling print in Opera and Chrome (Netscape).

Here’s the solution:

```
function init() {
  var objBrowse = window.navigator;
  if (objBrowse.appName == “Opera” || objBrowse.appName == “Netscape”) {
    setTimeout(‘window.print()’, 1000);
  } else {
    window.print();
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

Reference: http://danielbergsten.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/javascript-window-print-does-not-work-in-operachrome-browser/